# How to make shapes like these?

Tags: modeling, materials

[image: i want to learn how to make this type of spikey and sharp shapes also the material]

i want to learn how to make this type of spikey and sharp shapes also the material

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The image you shared seems to be a group cloth simulation works, perhaps? If not, then I suggest use lattice modifier, for instance: [image]

[image]